# ionic 3 - Error Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, ionic3

I create ionic 3 project and add file and transfer cordova plugin like this and cant able to run android using this command ionic cordova run android --prod

`Installing "cordova-plugin-file-transfer" for android
Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-file-transfer': CordovaError: Version of installed plugin: "cordova-plugin-file@4.3.3" does not satisfy dependency plugin requirement "cordova-plugin-file@^5.0.0". Try --force to use installed plugin as dependency.
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js:581:33
    at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:749:13)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:509:49
    at flush (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
Failed to restore plugin "cordova-plugin-file-transfer" from config.xml. You might need to try adding it again. Error: Version of installed plugin: "cordova-plugin-file@4.3.3" does not satisfy dependency plugin requirement "cordova-plugin-file@^5.0.0". Try --force to use installed plugin as dependency.
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/reactivespace/Library/Android/sdk
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home
Error: Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio,
or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle
in your path, or install Android Studio
[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova run android (exit code 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Download the latest Gradle distribution [here](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-bin.zip).

Then create a new directory **C:\Gradle** with File Explorer.

Unzip the content inside this folder.

After that, under **System Variables** select **Path**, then click **Edit**. Add an entry for **C:\Gradle\gradle-4.4\bin**. Click **OK** to save.

Restart your computer than give it another try.

Hope this steps can help you.